# Java Recursion problem , cant handle edge cases - due to ArrayIndexOutoOfBound

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DSA_First_Last_Occurence_Rec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2,2};
        int ae = 2;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(searchRange(arr,ae)));
    }
    // still many edge cases are not yet handled

    public static int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target) {
        return search(nums,target);
    }

    private static int[] search(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] ans = {-1,-1};
        ans[0] = help(nums, target, 0, nums.length-1, true);
        if (ans[0] != -1)
            ans[1] = help(nums, target, 0, nums.length-1, false);
        return ans;
    }

    private static int help(int[] nums, int target, int s, int e, boolean wh) {
        int ans = -1;
        int start = s;
        int end = e;
        if (start == -1 || end == -1)
            return -1;
        int mid = -1;
        while (start <= end) {
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            if (nums[mid] == target) {
                ans = mid;
                if (start == end)
                    return mid;
                if (!wh)
                    if (nums[mid+1] > target) {
                        return mid;
                    }
                    else {
                        return help(nums,target,mid+1,end,false);
                    }
                    if (mid >= 0 && nums[mid-1] < target) {
                        return mid;
                    }
                    else {
                        return help(nums, target, start, mid-1, true);
                    }
                }
                else if (mid <= nums.length && target < nums[mid])
                    end = mid - 1;
            else
                start = mid + 1;
        }
        if((start==end || start >end ) || nums[mid]!=target)
            return -1;
        return mid;
    }
}
```

As I have provided the above in which both elements are target elements and the only elements in the array, this gives array out of bound. I know my code is bad - and can be optimized in much better way.
But I wanted to try using recursion - and without any help from any references. So I may have made unnecessary comparisons, but those were made to handle errors.

---

*The code Works properly when target elements are not the corners and are present in the middle of array like {1,2,2,2,3,4} - this has correct output.*
**the problem comes in line 36 where I do `mid - 1 =` and the answer comes -1, for array index**
Hence please help me. I can't think of any more solution.

Comment: `if (mid >= 0 && nums[mid - 1] < target) {` - If `mid` happens to equal 0 then `[mid - 1]` will be **-1** which will generate the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. Change `mid >= 0` to `mid > 0`.

Comment: A test should also be done for: `if(nums[mid+1]>target) {`. If `mid` happens to be equal `nums.length - 1` then `[mid + 1]` will also generate an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**. Try changing to: `if (mid < (nums.length - 1) && nums[mid + 1] > target) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You don't always protect against out-of-range access with an array index:

  - `if (nums[mid + 1] > target)` needs to first check if `mid + 1` is still within range. If not, it should not evaluate this expression, but still execute the `if` block.
  - In the mirrored situation you *did* add a check: `if (mid >= 0 && nums[mid - 1] < target)`, but it is wrong. `mid` is already guaranteed to be non-negative at this point, and if it is 0, then `mid - 1` is still an invalid index. What needs to happen is that when `mid` is `start`, the array access is not performed, but the `if` block is still executed.
- You have mixed recursion and iteration: you should choose one or the other. Since you indicate you want to do this with recursion, you should not have the `while` loop. This also means you should not have code that updates `start` or `end` in order to make a next iteration. Instead make a recursive call and return its result.
- The initial `if (start == -1 || end == -1)` somehow sees a possibility for `start` to become negative, but this can never happen. On the other hand, this is where you should check what you had as `while` condition: when `start > end` you should return -1.

Not a problem, but:

- `mid <= nums.length` will always be true. No need to check that.
- If you would give your parameters more meaningful names (not `s` and `e`, but `start` and `end`) then you don't need those local variables.
- The value of `ans` is never used. You don't need this variable
- It is not necessary to treat `start == end` as a separate case. With the above corrections, this will be treated well by the other `if` statements.
- The index checks don't need to happen against 0 or `nums.length`. You have a range `start`-`end` which you can use for this purpose, which often will be a smaller window, and that way you can avoid some comparisons with array values (that would be outside this window).

Here is the corrected `help` function:

```
    private static int help(int[] nums, int target, int start, int end, boolean wh) {
        if (start > end) {
            return -1;
        }
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (nums[mid] == target) {
            if (!wh) {
                if (mid >= end || nums[mid + 1] > target) { 
                    return mid;
                }
                return help(nums, target, mid + 1, end, false);
            }
            if (mid <= start || nums[mid - 1] < target) {
                return mid;
            }
            return help(nums, target, start, mid - 1, true);
        }
        if (target < nums[mid]) {
            return help(nums, target, start, mid - 1, wh);
        }
        return help(nums, target, mid + 1, end, wh);
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was trying to handle every error that i got during debugging so i kept on adding new conditions to control those - and it made the code more complicated.

i never thought it would have been able to run with only 3-4 conditions.
thank you for your help and pointing out my mistakes , it made me realize where i was wrong and how i should have thought about it in different way.

Thanks ! it really helped me to grow in this topic of recursion - i was literally stuck whole day, resolving this.